# How to number grouped rows

Tags: sql, presto

There is a table in which data of the video viewing log as follows is stored.

```
|user_id| status |     time         |
-------------------------------------
|user_a |start   |2019-06-18 00:00:00|
|user_a |progress|2019-06-18 00:00:05|
|user_a |progress|2019-06-18 00:00:10|
|user_a |complete|2019-06-18 00:00:15|
|user_a |start   |2019-06-18 00:10:00|
|user_a |complete|2019-06-18 00:10:05|
|user_a |start   |2019-06-19 00:10:00|
|user_a |start   |2019-06-19 00:10:05|
|user_a |progress|2019-06-19 00:10:10|
|user_b |start   |2019-06-18 00:20:00|
|user_b |progress|2019-06-18 00:20:05|
|user_b |progress|2019-06-18 00:20:10|
```

I want to give the same number to the rows from status 'start' to 'start' every user_id like below.

```
id|user_id| status |     time         |
-------------------------------------
 1|user_a |start   |2019-06-18 00:00:00|
 1|user_a |progress|2019-06-18 00:00:05|
 1|user_a |progress|2019-06-18 00:00:10|
 1|user_a |complete|2019-06-18 00:00:15|
 2|user_a |start   |2019-06-18 00:10:00|
 2|user_a |complete|2019-06-18 00:10:05|
 3|user_a |start   |2019-06-19 00:10:00|
 4|user_a |start   |2019-06-19 00:10:05|
 4|user_a |progress|2019-06-19 00:10:10|
 1|user_b |start   |2019-06-18 00:20:00|
 1|user_b |progress|2019-06-18 00:20:05|
 1|user_b |progress|2019-06-18 00:20:10|
```

Is there a way to aggregate with sql?
I am using presto.

Answer (score 1):

Use a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*, 
       sum(case when status = 'start' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by user_id order by time) as id
from t;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/SJJ88316)</kbd>